# How do I get the logo path?

Tags: 7, media

I have a custom logo and I have tried to get his path in this way `theme_get_setting('logo_path')`, but no expected result.

I am using the code in a custom block, in input PHP.

Comment: Where are you using this code? Have you tried `theme_get_setting('logo_path', 'THEME_NAME')`, replacing THEME_NAME with the name of your theme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`logo_path` seems to only be set if you override the theme's default logo via its theme settings. To get the default logo, use `theme_get_setting('logo')`.

Comment: But why the result of `theme_get_setting('logo')` is empty string ? I have set my custom logo in `/admin/appearance/setting`

Comment: Why when Logo is deactivate from theme `TOGGLE DISPLAY -
Enable or disable the display of certain page elements.` the  `theme_get_setting('logo')` has no results. Why ?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Use `<a href="<?php echo theme_get_setting('logo');?>">` in a PHP code block to show the logo in your own block.

Answer (score 4):

```
global $base_url;
drupal_theme_initialize();

if (!$logo = theme_get_setting('logo_path')) {
    $logo = theme_get_setting('logo');
}

if (!empty($logo)) {
  // [1]
  // Remove the base URL from the result returned by theme_get_setting('logo').
  // If you don't need the relative path, you can remove this code.
  if (strpos($logo, $base_url) === 0) {
    $logo = drupal_substr($logo, drupal_strlen($base_url));
  }
  // [1]
  // …
}
```

The call to [drupal_theme_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_initialize/7) is not strictly necessary, and it doesn't do anything if the global variable `$theme` is already initialized.
The code is removing the base URL because the value reported from `theme_get_setting('logo')` is an absolute path; if you don't need a relative path to access the file, then the part between `// [1]` can be removed.

When the logo has been disabled in the theme settings, `theme_get_setting('logo')` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I replaced the code in `[1]` with `$logo = file_create_url($logo);` in order to get the full URL path of the logo (with the http://).