# Get the Dimensions of the Theme Logo

Tags: files

In Drupal 7 theme settings, you can upload a logo.
How do you print the width and height of this logo in your theme?

---

**Background Research:**

[`theme_get_setting('logo')`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/how-to-get-the-logo-path-in-drupal-7) lets you get the path of a logo uploaded in the theme settings.

[`image_get_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_get_info/7) lets you get the height and width of an image.

However, `image_get_info(theme_get_setting('logo'))` does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code. (Add error checking where necessary.)

```
  $image_url = parse_url(theme_get_setting('logo'));
  $image_path = str_replace(base_path(), realpath(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/', $image_url['path']);
  $info = image_get_info($image_path);
  $height = $info['height'];
  $width = $info['width'];
```

As side note, `theme_get_settings('logo_path')` returns the path of the uploaded file used as logo. While `theme_get_settings('logo')` always return a value, whatever the logo is the default one, or one that has been uploaded, `theme_get_settings('logo_path')` returns a value when the logo has been uploaded.
The value returned for "logo_path" is similar to public://logo.png. To obtain the real path, you would use code similar to the following one.

```
  if ($image_uri = theme_get_settings('logo_path')) {
    if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($image_uri)) {
      $image_path = $wrapper->realpath();
    }
    elseif (!empty($image_uri)) {
      $image_path = realpath($image_uri);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You can also use url() with absolute and aliased keys set to TRUE and path set to the front page.  It will give an absolute URL to the front page so you can str_replace.

Comment: If there aren't modules implementing `hook_outbound_alter()` that alter the URL for the front page, it can work too.

Comment: Thanks! I used to put it everywhere even for files. Thanks for the outbound alter tip. Even though it's not used everywhere that can beat my bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `theme_get_setting('logo')` gives you the *URL* of the logo, not the *path* (which is what you need in order to use `image_get_info`).  The reason your call to `image_get_info` returns nothing (actually `FALSE`) is that you're feeding it garbage.  As the old saying goes: GIGO.

You need to do something like the following:

```
$filepath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/logo.png';
$image_info = image_get_info($filepath);
$width  = $image_info['width'];
$height = $image_info['height'];
```

(My method for sniffing the $filepath is probably not optimal, as it assumes the logo file is named "logo.png", which is not always the case, but I hope you get the idea.)